# Count two columns in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have looked around and haven't found anything that seem to solve my problem.

I have 2 tables latlista and latlike. I want to base my query on latlista and count the times the same ID is in the latlista table, which works fine with the code below.

```
SELECT latlista.id, latlista.artist, latlista.lat, latlista.`user`, latlista.songadd, count(latlike.latid) AS LikeCount
FROM latlista LEFT JOIN latlike ON latlike.latid=latlista.id
GROUP BY latlista.id, latlista.artist, latlista.lat, latlista.`user`
ORDER BY LikeCount DESC
```

The latlista table looks like this:

```
ID
latid
user
```

Now I also, in the same query want to count how many times the same user exists for the same latid using my session variable MM_Username.

Is this possible and if so how?

Hope my jibberich makes any sense, otherwise please ask!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I, for one, am not quite sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe? if im understanding your question properly.. let me know if you need changes to this.. and if you do provide some sample data so that I can build it how you want it

```
SELECT 
    l.id, 
    l.artist, 
    l.lat, 
    l.`user`, 
    l.songadd, 
    count(l.latid) AS LikeCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(latlista.id) FROM latlista WHERE latlista.`user` LIKE "your_uer_name_here") as num_times
FROM latlista as l LEFT JOIN latlike ON latlike.latid=l.id
GROUP BY l.id, l.artist, l.lat, l.`user`
ORDER BY LikeCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks!
I highly appreciate your help, however I get the following error " MySQL Error#: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2"... 
I'm not to very well educated in SQL and I'm using dreamweaver to build the website where I'm usin the SQL and Wampserver as local webserver. Don't know if this will help in solving my issues. I have tried sub queries before and nothing seem to work...

Comment: well what do you have at line 2?